# Pronoun usage: that vs one

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns, writing-style

I've encountered a sentence on English Wiktionary:

> The company's 2005 revenue exceeds that of 2004

Can I use *one* instead of *that* in the sentence? And *that one*? And, basically, what is the difference between them from the viewpoint of style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *The company's 2005 revenue exceeds that of 2004*, *that*  is a demonstrative pronoun with 'that of 2004' standing for 'The company's 2004 revenue'.

In *My new jacket is better than that one I bought three years ago*, *that* is a determiner, 'singling out' (ie pointing to) the [rest of the] noun clause/group. It is no longer 'stand-alone'.

Using 'that one' doesn't sound right in your example, as the company's yearly revenue is such a unique and well known concept. You *could* use the construction idiomatically in other circumstances:

*This nail extractor is much better than that [stupid] [old] one of
John's.*